# Meaning of Sophrosyne and Polytelei

Tags: greek, gender, bible

I would like to know a real ancient Greek meaning of sophrosyne and polytelei when we talking of clothing. Sophrosyne is translated as self-control or sound mind but also self-restraint

So range of meanings, so you either cannot wear any nice clothes (self-restraint) or wear them in moderation (self-control). For Socrates it was more as self restraint and for Arystoteles and Plato more as moderation, so how do I know what Paul meant in 1 Timothy 2:9?

> Likewise also women should adorn themselves in respectable apparel,
> with modesty and **self-control** [σωφροσύνης], not with braided hair
> or gold or pearls or **costly** [πολυτελεῖ] clothing,

Also Polytelei - my Bible say costly but if you do a research it means very costly, very precious, luxurious. So can we only buy cheap clothes so we avoid any expense or we avoid those really costly and status like clothes/bags/shoes. I found polytelei once translated as Magnificent as well but in my Bible only say costly so now all the clothes as costly so should we only buy cheaper ones we can find?

Answer (score 0):

According to BDAG, these words (each occurring only three times in the NT) have the following meanings:

**σωφροσύνη (sóphrosuné)**

> 1. generally, soundness of mind, reasonableness, rationality, eg, Acts 26:5
> 2. practice of prudence, good judgement, moderation, self-control as exercise of care and intelligence appropriate to circumstances, eg, 1 Tim 2;9, 15

Barnes comments on 1 Tim 2:9

> **And sobriety** - The word here used means, properly, "sanity;" then sober-mindedness, moderation of the desires and passions. It is
> opposed to all that is frivolous, and to all undue excitement of the
> passions. The idea is, that in their apparel and deportment they
> should not entrench on the strictest decorum. Doddridge.

**πολυτελής (polutelés)**

> pertaining to being of great value or worth, ordinarily of relatively
> high degree on a monetary scale, (very) expensive, costly, eg, Mark
> 14:3, 1 Tim 2:9, 1 Peter 3:4

Again, Barnes suggests this:

> **Costly array** - Expensive dress. This is forbidden - for it is foolish, and the money thus employed may be much more profitably used
> in doing good. "Costly array" includes that which can be ill afforded,
> and that which is inconsistent with the feeling that the principle
> ornament is that of the heart.

Comment: Thank you, My friend once suggested that sophrosyne can not be translated as modertaion because in Plato times it meant more like aesceticism so as little as possible? I just don't know how much is to much, as someone with severe scrupulosity I tend to overthink this. I always loved fashion and always thought this talent is from God but now it seems like every nicer dress is prohibited and we should only wear cheapest possible things..

Comment: Aso, in Bible Hub they translated Sophron as Chaste, unadorned, plain etc, does it mean that sophrosyne means unadorned and chaste too?

Comment: @monique - all words have a range of meaning and the precise meaning is usually deduced from the context.  I have quoted the best lexicon in my answer.